# Using Gmail smtp service

Tags: php, smtp, gmail

I am trying to send email from my server with gmail smtp. I am using following code:

```
    $mesaj=$this->load->view('main/mail.php',$token,true);
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['wordwrap'] = FALSE;
    $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $config['smtp_user'] = 'info@site.com';
    $config['smtp_pass'] = 'password';
    $config['smtp_port'] = '465';     
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->from('info@site.com');
    $this->email->to($email);
    $this->email->subject('Subject');
    $this->email->message($mesaj);
    $this->email->send(); 
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

But I am getting following error:

```
SMTP ERROR OCCURED. AUTH LOGIN COMMAND COULD NOT SEND
```

I have no SSL certificate on my server. Is this could be the problem ? How can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The port 465 is reserved for SSL requests on the smtp.gmail.com server.
It doesn't look like you specified the authorization method here (none / ssl / tsl).

I'm not too familiar with PHP, so I don't know exactly how you'd set it...